# Many to Many Relationships with Properties in JPA

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, jpa, eclipselink, h2

I have 2 entities :
Entity A which contains : ID,Name,Price
Entity B which contains : ID,Date,TotalSum
The relationship between these two entities is many to many with properties : A_Count
As a result we have 3 tables in the DataBase :
Table A : ID (primary key),Name,Price
Table B : ID (primary key),Date,TotalSum
Table A_B : (A_ID,B_ID) as primary key,A_Count
Is there a way in JPA annotations to create this kind of relationships (n2n with properties) or do I have to create a new entity (or a class) for it ?
I'm using EclipseLink with H2 and MySQL (don't ask)

Comment: where in your classes is "A_Count" stored? because, after all, JPA persists what is in your classes

Comment: As I have said A_Count is stored in A_B table as an attribute for A,B many to many relation

Comment: JPA can only persist what is in the classes. Since it isn't in the classes you can conclude that you CANNOT persist it as you want with those classes. There are ample questions in here for M-N with attributes/properties asking the exact same thing. If you want some extra column persisting then you change your classes to have an intermediate class with the "count"